# Using enums in functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, enums, arduino

This code is developed on VS2015 with the Visual Micro add-in for Arduino and is part of my arduino program.This was also posted on the Arduino stackexchange site with minimal responses.

Given the following enums

```
enum RelayState { RELAY_OFF = HIGH, RELAY_ON = LOW };
enum class CrossingZoneState: uint8_t {
    CROSSINGZONE_CLEAR = 0, // no train in crossing area, also initialized state
    CROSSINGZONE_OCCUPIED = 1, // train detected by the entry sensor
    CROSSINGZONE_EXITING = 2  // train detected by the exit sensor, when sensor clears, state= Clear
};
```

Where RELAY_OFF = HIGH, HIGH is #define HIGH 0x1 which I assume is a C++/Arduino constant? because I didn't define it. And RELAY_ON = LOW, LOW is 0x0

in the following function I get the error that follows.

```
CrossingZoneState CheckEntrySensor(uint8_t esp) {
    //esp, short for entry sensor pin
    if (digitalRead(esp) == HIGH)
    {
        state = CrossingZoneState::CROSSINGZONE_CLEAR;
        return state;
    }
    else if (digitalRead(esp) == LOW)
    {
        state = CrossingZoneState::CROSSINGZONE_OCCUPIED;
        return state;
    }
    // if the digital read errs, return the current state so it re-runs
    return state;
};

boolean throwRelayAndCheckStatus(uint8_t relayNumber, RelayState relayState)    {

    int testInt = 0;
    if (relayState == RelayState::RELAY_OFF)
    {
        testInt = 1;
    }
    digitalWrite(relayNumber, relayState);
    if (digitalRead(relayNumber) == testInt) {
        return true;
    };
    return false;
};
```

I tried having RelayState be an enum class as well but was getting similar type errors. Here is the error from VS2015 with the code shown above. (ModelRRXingStateMachine is the name of the file)

> Compiling debug version of 'ModelRRXingStateMachine' for 'Arduino/Genuino Uno'
>   ModelRRXingStateMachine.ino:11:55: error: 'RelayState' has not been declared
>   :boolean throwRelayAndCheckStatus(uint8_t relayNumber, RelayState relayState)
>   ModelRRXingStateMachine.ino:2:1: error: 'CrossingZoneState' does not name a type
>   :CrossingZoneState CheckEntrySensor(byte esp)
>   Error compiling project sources

I'm not a professional programmer and am new to C++, usually writing in C# or VB.Net so I'm not sure what the compiler is looking for here, both enums are declared and one is declared with a type. Also, the VS code editor is showing no errors, the errors shown above show up in the error window when I try to build.

Comment: Without the complete project it's hard to tell exactly what the problem is, but suffice it to say that `RelayState` hasn't been declared by the time that `throwRelayAndCheckStatus` is compiled, and a similar situation is probably true for `CrossingZoneState` and `CheckEntrySensor`.  There may be more problems beyond that too, especially since you're not casting `relayState` to whatever `digitalWrite` expects.

Comment: both enums are declared after all the include statements, how is it possible they aren't compiled before the function? The entire program is quite long Ill post it if required. digitalWrite takes HIGH or LOW and that's what is being passed to it.

Comment: Are they declared in the same .cpp file in the same namespace? Are they declared before the functions which use them?

Comment: Unless there's something different about the Arduino flavor of C++, function definitions shouldn't have trailing semicolons.

Comment: @Robk yes they are

Comment: See my reply at http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/23272/using-enums-in-functions/23279#23279 . And pls avoid cross-posting.

Comment: @Keith Thompson : You are right, of course, but strangely enough the compiler doesn't complain about this. I wonder if extraneous semicolons outside functions are valid C++. Too lazy to check though...

Comment: @Alphonsos_Pangas: The compiler is probably treating the `;` as an empty declaration. I don't think there is such a thing in standard C++, but g++, for example, supports it as an extension (and complains about it with `-pedantic`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to, of course, move the problem code to a header file. So I moved this code to a new header file and included it in the main program and now it builds.

```
// ModelRRCrossing.h

#ifndef _MODELRRCROSSING_h
#define _MODELRRCROSSING_h

#if defined(ARDUINO) && ARDUINO >= 100
    #include "arduino.h"
#else
    #include "WProgram.h"
#endif
#pragma once
// Arduino Digital I/O pin numbers for MEGA
//note: digital pins 30-45
//MEGA is a MUST for this project
enum {
    Relay1 = 30, Relay2 = 31, Relay3 = 32, Relay4 = 33, Relay5 = 34, Relay6 = 35,
    Relay7 = 36, Relay8 = 37, Relay9 = 38, Relay10 = 39, Relay11 = 40,
    Relay12 = 41, Relay13 = 42, Relay14 = 43, Relay15 = 44, Relay16 = 45
};

enum RelayState { RELAY_OFF = HIGH, RELAY_ON = LOW };
enum class CrossingZoneState : uint8_t {
    CROSSINGZONE_CLEAR = 0, // no train in crossing area, also initialized state
    CROSSINGZONE_OCCUPIED = 1, // train detected by the entry sensor
    CROSSINGZONE_EXITING = 2  // train detected by the exit sensor, when sensor clears, state= Clear
};
#endif
```